Generator of an analytic semigroup
Perhaps I have a naive question. My question is as follows:
When we consider a Cauchy proposition of the following form:
$$ 
\begin{cases}
x'(t)= -Ax(t)+ F(t,x(t)) &\text{for}\  t> 0 \\ 
x(0)=x_0 \in X_{\alpha}, 
\end{cases}
$$
where $X_{\alpha}$ is the domain of the fractional power operator $A^{\alpha}$ equipped with the graph norm.
Why do we need that the operator $-A$ that generates an anlytic semigroup and not the operator $A$? And why do we need the analycity of the semigroup in order to treat the problem?

If you ignore $F$ and the Banach space setting (imagine $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ an $n \times n$ matrix), what functional relation $x'(t) = \dots$ does $x(t) = e^{At}x_0$ satisfy, where $e^{At}$ is the semigroup generated by $A$?

Of course we are talking about an infinite dimensional case. I do not know if I have understood your question, but I believe that whenever the operator $A$ generates a semigroup $e^{tA}$, then the solutions take the following form: $x(t)=e^{tA}x_0+\int_{0}^{t}e^{(t-s)A}F(s,x(s)),ds$. My question is why we need the operator $-A$ to generate an analytic semigroup, rather than the operator $A$ generating an analytic semigroup?

Take a derivative the expression that you wrote down and check the sign and compare to what you write in OP. This is what I was trying to point you to.

Sorry, I was not more precise in my question. If we consider the following problem:
\begin{cases}
x'(t)= Ax(t)+ F(t,x(t)) &\text{for}\  t> 0 \
x(0)=x_0 \in X_{\alpha}.
\end{cases}
Why do not we suppose only that the operator A generates an analytic semigroup? In other words, in the literature related to this kind of systems, they treat the following problem:
\begin{cases}
x'(t)= -Ax(t)+ F(t,x(t)) &\text{for}\  t> 0 \
x(0)=x_0 \in X_{\alpha},
\end{cases}
by assuming that $-A$ generates an analytic semigroup.

A matter of convention, taste and mathematical upbringing. :-)

Thank you sir for the reaction about the question.
